# How to find my device's CSC (Country Specific Code)

Tags: csc, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I bought a Samsung Galaxy on an auction website, with no clear indication of where it comes from.

Now, to root the device or restore it, I need its **Country Specific Code**.

**Question:** How do I find the CSC of my device?

## What I tried

1. Installed the [Phone Info SAM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo) app by vndnguyen.
2. Ran it (works even without root).
3. Opened the `CSC CODE` tab.

   - `Product Code` ends with `TPA` (Panama)
   - `Firmware's CSC Code` is `DBT` (Germany)
   - `Active CSC Code` is `TPA`
   - `Available CSC Codes` lists about a hundred codes.

Some website claims to find your CSC from your IMEI number by taking the 7th and 8th digits, which for me are `10`, which supposedly means Finland.

That's many different codes, so I am not sure which one I should use. Or maybe both of these methods are actually completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Some websites claim to find your CSC from your IMEI number, but I doubt them. This method looks more reliable:

1. Install the [Phone Info SAM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo) app by vndnguyen.
2. Run it.
3. Open the `CSC CODE` tab.
4. The `Active CSC Code` is the code you need.

It works even without root.